# Creating and querying a temporary table-skipLeadingRows

Tags: google-bigquery

```
    bq --location=US query --external_table_definition=sales::Region:STRING,Quarter:STRING,Total_sales:INTEGER@CSV=gs://mybucket/sales.csv 'SELECT Region,Total_sales FROM sales;'
```

in the above query will it be possible to mention skipLeadingRows option.

Thanks,
Sreekanth

Answer (score 0):

We can use `-skip_leading_rows=1` option for skipping the leading rows.